# Automatic Id generation with SQL stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a database of toys management system with two tables:

1. `toys` (toyid, toyname, category, price, quantity)
2. `category` (categoryid, categoryname, description)

The `toyid` in `toys` will be automatically generated according to the category selected.

For example if I select category as `infant`, then the produced id like `IN100`.

And if I select `Grown up` the id like `GU100`.

And each category has its own increment id..

```
IN100,IN101,IN102,....
GU100,GU101,GU102,,,,
```

How will I automatically generate the series like above?

How I will execute this with the help of a stored procedure?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Features like this are **highly** vendor-specific - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: As Marc wrote solution depends on RDBMS. For example Oracle looks like that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40037062/how-to-create-a-database-sequence-which-is-different-for-different-channels/40041823#40041823 but this is not universal solution. Please tell us what DB you're using.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest that you *do not* do this.  Simply make `toyid` an identity column that auto-increments.  Such synthetic keys are much more flexible than informative keys.

Consider:  What will you do if you split an existing category into two categories?  What will you do if you combine two existing categories into a new category?  What will the ids mean if you have multiple categories that would have the same two-digit prefix?

Instead, just use synthetic keys and use the database to look up the category when you need to get it.

That said, if you disregard this advice, then you will need triggers on the `toys` table to create the appropriate id.

Answer (score -1):

DECLARE @Id INT = 0,@CatCode VARCHAR(50) = ''

SELECT @Id = MAX(toyid) FROM toys WHERE category = your_Selected_Category
SELECT @CatCode = categoryCode FROM category WHERE categoryid = your_Selected_Categoryid

IF ISNULL(@Id,'') = '' 
  SET @Id = @CatCode + RIGHT( ( '100'+ 1 ),3)
ELSE
  SET @Id = @CatCode + RIGHT( ( '100'+ ( @Id + 1 ) ),3)