# Hibernate create sequence in java then get next value with load balancing

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, weblogic, load-balancing

Here's my problem :

1 - I read a file and split a certain range in each row to extract a code.*(done)*

2 - I need To **create a sequence** for the extracted code, so I can get next value for each.

3- I need to be sure that each "nextvalue" would be unique because of the  **Load Balancing** on two weblogic

4 - I'm using **Oracle** so I can't just use an auto incremente

Given all this all I can do in Database side is to create the table wich will contain all sequences, then auto increment the needed column. Maybe I got it wrong.

If you can help, thank you a lot

Comment: what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40037062/how-to-create-a-database-sequence-which-is-different-for-different-channels isn't it what you need? One sequence per one weblogic?

Comment: @Jobin The issue is how to create dynamicaly the sequences and then incremente the wanted field, which is in my case CURRENT_NUMBER. I know sequence must be created in database layer and managed by the database it self.
But I need to create sequence for lot of codes, for instance :
Code CURRENT_NUMBER
001   0001
030   0001
060   0003

I need to be able to increment the number for each of my codes
My codes are also inserted in java.

Comment: @Kacper : no :/ but thank you

Comment: yes that is fine.. you can use @GenericGenerator or programmatically using "select SEQUENCE_NAME.nextval as num from dual"

Comment: thank you @Jobin forget about the sequence the real problem is :
**How can increment a value (update with +1) and be sure that the two servers don't get same value because the two are using one and same database.**
Thank you in advance